# Find some value of $n$ such that $|a_n - a| < 10^{-1000}$

Tags: real-analysis

Problem: Let $x_0$ be a fix, positive real number. The real sequence $\left(a_n\right)$ is defined by $$a_n = \frac{\sqrt{n} (\sqrt{x_0 n} + 1) }{n+1} $$ with a limit $a$.
Find some $n_0$ such that $$|a_n - a| < 10^{-1000} \qquad \forall n > n_0$$
 It is not necessary to find the smallest $n_0$ for the condition to hold.

My results so far: I found that $\left(a_n\right)$ converges to $\sqrt{x_0}$, and it is

$$
|a_n - a| = \frac{|\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{x_0}|}{n+1} < \frac{|\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{x_0}|}{n}.
$$

Here I'm stuck. I tried to assume that $\sqrt{n}- \sqrt{n_0}$ is positive, rearrange, square and solve a quadrative equation for $n$, but I doubt that this makes sense.

EDIT
I did a typo, now its fixed. I typed $\sqrt{x_0}$ instead of $\sqrt{n}$

Comment: You should rather find that $a_n\to 0$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I'm sorry, I misstyped the equation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $n\ge x_0/4$,
$$
\begin{align}
\left|\,\frac{\sqrt{n}(\sqrt{x_0n}+1)}{n+1}-\sqrt{x_0}\,\right|
&=\left|\,\frac{(n\sqrt{x_0}+\sqrt{n})-(n\sqrt{x_0}+\sqrt{x_0})}{n+1}\,\right|\\
&=\left|\,\frac{\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{x_0}}{n+1}\,\right|\\
&\lt\frac1{\sqrt{n+1}}
\end{align}
$$
If $n\ge\max(10^{2000},x_0/4)$, then the error is less than $10^{-1000}$

---

To clarify the last inequality, note that if $n\ge x_0/4$, we have $\sqrt{x_0}\le2\sqrt{n}$, and therefore
$$
\sqrt{n+1}\ge\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{x_0}\ge-\sqrt{n}\ge-\sqrt{n+1}
$$
Thus,
$$\left|\,\frac{\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{x_0}}{n+1}\,\right| \le\frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{n+1} =\frac1{\sqrt{n+1}}$$

Comment: Could you show me how you arrived at the last inequlity?

Answer (score 1):

For $n>x_0$ we get
\begin{align*}
a_n-\sqrt{x_0}&=\frac{\sqrt{n}\left(\sqrt{x_0n}+1\right)}{n+1}-\sqrt{x_0}\\
&=\frac{n\sqrt{x_0}+\sqrt{n}-n\sqrt{x_0}-\sqrt{x_0}}{n+1}\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{x_0}}{n+1}\\
&<\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n}
\end{align*}
it follows 
$$n>\text{max}(x_0,10^{2000})\quad\implies\quad|a_n-\sqrt{x_0}|<10^{-1000}$$

Comment: Thank you, but why is the limit 0?

Comment: Okay, this was my bad.